# Is there any alternative way to load external site's content in our angular web app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I used a iframe to load a external sites but some of the sites are not load due to a security header x-frame-options:[deny/sameorigin] .

Is there any alternative way to load any external sites in our app.

Answer (score 1):

In a single sentence, it is **impossible** to make it work with all the external sites within your html using security compliant browsers.

You can try calling an ajax call, get data and use innerHTML to upload content. But it requires CORS enabled on the external site and also actions might not work as you only load html content. Angular might block innerHTML, you might need to relax that exception as well in angular.